# Time complexity of Random Gaussian Function

Tags: c++

I have created an implementation of Cross Entropy Minimization method in C++ taking reference from the Ruby Code given http://www.cleveralgorithms.com/nature-inspired/probabilistic/cross_entropy.html

I am not able to understand how the random_gaussian function is related with the normal distribution and what it is exactly doing. Also, I am unable to find out complexity of this function. Kindly help me with these two things.

```
    double random_gaussian(double mean , double stdev)
    {
          double u1,u2,w;
          do {
            u1 = 2*((double)rand()/RAND_MAX) - 1;
            u2 = 2*((double)rand()/RAND_MAX) - 1;
            w = u1*u1 + u2 * u2;
          } while( w >= 1 );

          w = sqrt(( -2.0 * log(w ))/w);
          return mean + ( u2* w ) * stdev;
    }
```

Here is the C++ code http://pastebin.com/Q4c73Kdi . The program is for solving AX = B and it's working fine.

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11 I would recommend using std::normal_distribution instead,  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/normal_distribution/. Generally is not safe to use std::rand, Stephan T. Lavavej supported this with his presentation rand() Considered Harmful http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Don't we need a trap for handling very small `w`?

Comment: @Keith: perhaps the code implicitly uses the property of a typical `rand()` implementation (linear congruential generator) that no two consecutive values are zeroes? I'm not saying it's a good assumption to use though.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q4c73Kdi You can see the code here. Thanks for all of your advices.

Comment: @Gassa. Excellent point - although it needs `rand()` to not return `RAND_MAX/2` twice in a row. But importantly, you're saying that the successive calls to `rand()` are of course not independent random numbers, with some subsequent effect on the resulting gaussian. I guess `RAND_MAX` is *usually* odd, so you won't get this case.

Comment: @Keith: Yeah, you are right, it is RAND_MAX/2 and not zero. If RAND_MAX is indeed odd, and the doubles are more precise than the return type of rand() (which is true if rand() is int16 or int32), it suffices for the algorithm to work. And these facts can be at least asserted for at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `do...while` block generates a point in the square with corners (±1, ±1) until the point fits into a circle of radius 1 centered in the origin. The expected number of iterations is the ratio of areas, which is the constant 4 / π, or O(1) in big-O-notation.

As for how the process is related to Gaussian distribution, it's an application of [Box-Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform#Polar_form). [Here](http://www.taygeta.com/random/gaussian.html) is another page with a bit of explanation which also contains your piece of code.